# Change the Activity Type of the user rich presence(Playing to Listening)

Tags: javascript, discord

I would like to change the activity type of my rich presence from playing to listening. Rich presence is for myself, not a bot.

Code looks like this until now:

```
const DiscordRPC = require('discord-rpc'); 
const client = new DiscordRPC.Client({ transport: 'ipc' }); 
require('dotenv').config(); 

(async () => {
    client.on('ready', async () => { 
        await client.setActivity({ 
            // buttons: [{ label: "Button Title Here", url: "Link For Button Here" }],
            details: "Listening music",
            largeImageKey: "spotifypng",
            largeImageText: "Spotify",
            type: false,
            instance: false,
            startTimestamp: new Date()
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));

        console.log("Discord Rich Presence has been enabled.");
    });

    await client.login({ clientId: process.env.applicationID }).catch(console.error);
})();
```

Comment: This is late, but ```type: 2```?